# Find Coordinate Vector with Respect to Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

[Linear Algebra Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyKKo.png)

I am trying to check my answer and my understanding is that the coefficients on the vectors form the columns of the change of basis matrix from B to B'. The change of basis matrix is therefore: $$\Biggl( \begin{matrix} 2 & -1 & -1 \\-1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 6\end{matrix} \Biggl)$$

Do I then multiply that change of basis matrix by the vector $$[v]_B=\Bigg(\begin{matrix} 2 \\ 5 \\ -4\end{matrix} \Bigg)$$ to get the answer of $$[v]_{B'}=\Bigg(\begin{matrix} 3 \\ -5 \\ 12\end{matrix}\Bigg)$$ Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change of basis can be a bit tricky at first, but it's the other way around. Your matrix $M$ is made of the base vectors of $B'$ in base $B$, and this is the change of basis **from** $B'$ **to** $B$ .

Take any vector $[v]_{B'} = (a,b,c)$ with respects to basis $B' = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$, that is, we can write $v = a u_1 + b u_2 + c u_3$. Then, in basis $B$ this yields $[v]_{B} = a (u_1)_B + b (u_2)_B + c (u_3)_B = [u_1 | u_2 | u_3] (a,b,c) = M [v]_{B'}$.

So $M$ takes a vector expressed in $B'$ and expresses it in $B$, then $M^{-1}$ does the reverse, what you want is $[v]_{B'} = M^{-1} [v]_B$.